# mySQL Query Error at line 1

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database

I wrote this mySQL query and I keep getting an error. Included are the query and the error:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO wp_usermeta(umeta_id, user_id, meta_key, meta_value) 
VALUES(NULL, $value, $lastkey, $time())") or die(mysql_error());
```

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Quote your values, they're strings. Plus this `$time()` that's wrong. It's either a variable or a function; take your pick.

Comment: I'd really would have liked to post an answer, but I don't have the full picture to build you a proper frame.

Answer (score 0):

If your column in 'umeta_id' is default NULL then you don't need to specify it on the insert. 'CURTIME()' is an SQL function that returns current time. Should work if the column 'meta_value' is set to hold only time. I'm assuming you are using PHP. I've found including the variables in tick marks ' works. Also mysql_query is deprecated. You should use mysqli_query(yourDatabaseConnection, yourQuery)

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO wp_usermeta (user_id, meta_key, meta_value) 
VALUES ('$value', '$lastkey', CURTIME())") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing String thru query to mysql `Without` putting in Single/Double quotes. Use

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO wp_usermeta(umeta_id, user_id, meta_key, meta_value) 
VALUES(NULL, $value, '".$lastkey."', '".$time()."')") or die(mysql_error());
```

this query with string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

Check type of values was matched with database and `umeta_id` allow be null .
may be on of field has autoincrement or not null check database again .

Answer (score 0):

you should use NOW()

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO wp_usermeta(umeta_id, user_id, meta_key, meta_value) 
VALUES(NULL, $value, $lastkey, NOW())") or die(mysql_error());
```